# Iteration algorithm computation TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow() : 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, iteration, typeerror, exponential

[iteration algorithm code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yW41.png)

Code attached at image link above

```
 input:
  x = value at which the series is evaluated 
  es = stopping criterion
  maxit = maximum number of iteration

  output:
  fx =estimated function value
  ea = approximate relative error  
  iter = number of iterations
```

Comment: please provide the code, and provide the output of the error so people get a better idea of what you are working with. This question is missing most of the useful context.

Comment: @MrE my bad forgot to attach image earlier

Answer (score 0):

In your code, remove the commas after the variables

in Python, a comma creates a tuple

```py
iter = 1, # <-- this creates a tuple iter = (1,)
```